# Scaffolding Db Context and automatically remove the redundant usings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-database-first, ef-core-3.1

In our project, we use EF Core Db first approach.
After I ran a scaffolding command:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -Force -DataAnnotations -UseDatabaseNames -Schema dbo,bank`

in our ASP.NET Core application to generate dbContext and entity models based on the existing database schema I noticed that some of the entity classes get extra redundant/unused `usings`. This is an example, where the `using System;` and using `System.Collections.Generic;` are redundant:
[image]

Is there any option to not generate these redundant `using`s? I cannot see anything related in the ef core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext)...
Cheers

Comment: Why do you care about those redundant using statements though?

Comment: We normally have convection in the codebase to clean up all the unused `usings` just to keep the code cleaner. Other than that as @Chris Pickford wrote in his answer it may have an impact on the compilation time.

Comment: The time to compile is negligible, even if it does add time, it's going to be microseconds. As for convention, I agree there shouldn't be any, but not for auto generated code. If you spend time removing them from there, they might just get added back in if you re-scaffold.

Comment: @DavidG of course I agree with you. I thought that there may be some option that I can pass into the scaffolding command but I think for now I leave this as is and just don't care about the extra usings that are added. It is not something that causes a big problem. Just only something to do with elegance, not a big deal though :D Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any argument you can pass to the EF binary that will strip unused `usings`, although given this is volatile/generated code the impact of not removing them is negligible.

Unused `usings` potentially might increase compile time by a miniscule amount but will have no impact on your runtime.

To attempt to answer your question though, you could create a pre-build script that cleans these generate files - I believe the [Power Commands Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) provides a tool for doing so but not sure if that could be automated.

Comment: I think your answer in enough for me, thanks ;)